# Writing text in QFile

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

Is there any differences in two ways of writing text in `QFile`?

By using `write` method:

```
QFile file("test.txt");
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    file.write("My Text\n");
}
file.close();
```

Or by using `QTextStream`:

```
QFile file("test.txt")
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
     QTextStream out(&file);
     out << "My Text\n";
}
file.close()
```

Which way is preferred? Is there any differences in performance?

Comment: it's a matter of usage. In your example there is not much difference. The hardcoded string in the first example will get converted to QByteArray and then written. In the second example it will not get converted (well maybe deeper under the hood). In case you are not going to use hardcoded string (most probably ;-) ) you may find it easier to use the latter, or even `QDataStream`

Comment: Which part of the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#details) did confuse you?

Comment: I've read it, but I don't understand differences `QTextStream` and `write`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QIODevice::write` is the low-level byte-oriented interface for writing raw data to a device. `QTextStream` is a higher-level interface for writing formatted text. `QTextStream` is probably implemented in terms of `QIODevice::write` under the hood.

One of the principal use cases for `QTextStream` is for writing `QString` data. The text stream handles the conversion from UTF-16 to your locale's default (usually 8-bit) encoding (or any other encoding via `QTextStream::setCodec`).

`QTextStream` almost certainly performs worse since it does more. However, in most use cases the difference will be negligible. If you're building a big string of raw data manually, then you should probably use `QIODevice::write`. If you want to write formatted text (that may include `QString`), you should probably chose `QTextStream`.